# How to Unit Test this method with C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, mstest, fizzbuzz

I have the following method, which I want to perform a unit test on. Change can be made for the method signature:

```
public void PrintNumber()
{
    Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        if (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("[35]");
        else if (x % 3 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("[3]");
        else if (x % 5 == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("[5]");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    });
}
```

I have my own solution, but I want to find out if my version is the best.

Thanks!

Comment: You want us to write the test for you?  What have you tried?

Comment: You can't really TDD this method becuase it is already written; in TDD you write the test first.  You can however write a unit test for it.

Comment: What you mean, TDD Test?

Comment: He's not asking TDD, he's asking unit test

Comment: @George could be that the `tdd` tag is causing this confusion?

Comment: @George he was asking TDD, but edited the question.

Comment: To All, sorry for the confusion. I retified the wording.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to unit test this method, you need to wrap your `Console.WriteLine()` with a proxy class, and inject that class into your method.

```
public interface IWriter
{
    void Write(string text);
}

public class ConsoleWriter : IWriter
{
    public void Write(string text)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}

public class StubWriter : IWriter
{
    List<string> values = new List<string>();
    public void Write(string text)
    {
         values.Add(text);
    }

    public List<string> Values { get { return values; } }
}
```

With this structure you change your method signature to `PrintNumber(IWriter writer)` and call the writer.  In your test method you inject the `StubWriter`, in production you inject the `ConsoleWriter`.

Comment: +1, although I dont think the OP put any time into even bother solving this...  Plus the +1 is because I dont think the OP will mark any of these as answers...

Comment: Yes for sure he wont bother understanding this and it might look a bit diff in understanding this i guess :)
Btw good answer.

Comment: @Charles Graham Thank you for yoru solution. I have my own solution, but I want to find out if my version is the best.

Comment: Although this solution is correct, it can also be achieved by redirecting the `Console` class output using the `Console.SetOut()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to rewrite your method

```
public void PrintNumber(TextWriter writer, 
               Action<TextWriter, int> modHandler) {... }

public void HandleMod(TextWriter writer, int input) {...}
```

And some tests:

```
void Print_Number_Should_Enumerate_0to100 {...}
void Handle_Mod_Outputs_35_Only_When_Input_35 {...}
void Handle_Mod_Gets_Mod_3_Correct {...}
void Handle_Mode_Gets_Mod_5_Correct {...}
void Handle_Mode_Defaults_To_Outputting_Input {...}
```

And so on.

However, you can't TDD this - it's been written already.  [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) involves writing the tests first.   What you can do is write the tests, then *refactor* to make the tests work.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean unit test, you'd only be able to validate the output, as the method has no input.  I'd rewrite the signature as:

```
public void PrintNumber(TextWriter writer) // use writer.WriteLine instead of console.WriteLine
```

and then in the test pass in something like a StreamWriter hooked to a MemoryStream.  After calling the method from the test method, the output should be written to the MemoryStream, and you could validate that it produced the output that you expected.

EDIT: Neglected to add, in production if you really wanted it to write to the console, call it as follows:

```
PrintNumber(Console.Out);
```